# Why haven't my lavender cuttings developed roots despite growing?

Tags: propagation, cuttings, lavender

Our lavenders were planted as small plants last summer but most of them grew a lot during the summer and had beautiful flowers even in late autumn.

I like experimenting so I took and planted about sixty cuttings when I pruned them a few weeks ago. I'm keeping the cuttings indoors, not covered but I water the soil every other day or when needed.

It's been three weeks and they are growing lots of new leaves but I checked two of them and apparently they are not rooting. Is this normal, do you think they will root eventually or should I give up?

Comment: Don't give up! It takes more than 3 weeks to develop roots. If the cuttings still look alive, just keep them.

Comment: Thank you, @benn! The old leaves that they had when I planted them are drying out and dying but they keep growing new offshoots, so I'm confused. Maybe I just need to be more patient.

Comment: Your welcome, if new growth is visible the plant still takes up enough water without roots. It will develop roots when it needs more, I did this with lavender last year. I can't remember how long it took before they got roots, but I am sure that it took more than 3 weeks. So patience would really be a good thing!

Comment: That's encouraging to hear, and again, thank you. Good luck with your gardening!